# Gradle non-managed dependency from source

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I need to configure a dependency in gradle to the **source** of another project (`P1`). Unfortunately, it is not possible to get a jar of the said project, nor is it possible to configure it to use gradle (company restrictions).

Now, I am writing a new java project (`Pnew`) that depends on `P1`. Both projects are currently under development (even my work may include changes in `P1`).

By configuring an additional sourceSet

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir '../../P1/src'
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to get rid of my compile errors where I'm dependent of `P1`. But this did not help. Naturally all the classes of `P1` became part of `Pnew`, which is certainly not the intention.

My goal would be to something like:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: '../../P1/src/', include:'*.java')
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

How can I configure such a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Include a file named `settings.gradle` in the same directory where you have the `build.gradle` of `Pnew`. In this file put the following:

```
include 'P1'
project(':P1').projectDir = = new File(rootDir, '../path/P1/')
```

where **path** is the relative path to `P1 build.gradle` file.

Now in you `Pnew build.gradle` add the following:

```
dependencies {
      ...
      compile project(':P1')
      ...
}
```

With this you can compile your Pnew project using P1 as dependency.

** **EDIT** **

If the project is not a gradle project and you can not generate a jar from your project, then try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("relative/path/to/classes/dir")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, P1 is not (and for the next year) will not be under gradle control. Therefore, I believe this will not work.

Comment: Your 'edit' with the dependency on "classes" showed me the base of my problem: I need to be able to compile P1. This needs some information (which is usually stored in a build script). Therefore, I needed to start thinking differently.... At the end I was allowed to put P1 under gradle control (I could not believe what I heard!!!)